# How to display components according to the option selected in React?

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-router, frontend, web-frontend

I have 5 different components which are to be displayed on a page according to the option selected. The selector should always remain on the top of the page. How should I proceed with this? I'm very new to React so it'll be great if you give as much of the code as possible. Thanks a lot! :')

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple example for you:

```js
function Main() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState("1");

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setOption(e.target.value)}>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
      </select>
      <div className="component-container">
        {option === 1 && <ComponentOne />}
        {option === 2 && <ComponentTwo />}
        {option === 3 && <ComponentThree />}
        {option === 4 && <ComponentFour />}
        {option === 5 && <ComponentFive />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the following kind of component - `import React from 'react';

function ComponentOne(props) {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <h4>First</h4>
      </div>
    );
}

export default ComponentOne;  `  but I'm not being able to see anything on the page on selecting the value

Comment: Also, had to use `React.useState("1")`